# Animate listview items after reordering

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I have a listview which uses a custom ArrayAdapter. When I click an item it gets highlighted (the textview changes color). What I would want to achieve is that the highlighted row moves to the top of the list.
My code looks like that:

```
private void onRowClick(....) {
    highlightRow(position);
    reorderItems();
    // animate here?
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    // or here?
}
```

I don't know much about android animations, so don't know where exactly animate the list items.
Thank's.